# Lookup all columns in excel with same ending

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have a sheet with many variables, one per column. I want to quickly reduce the sheet to columns with variables that end in the same string for example. is there a good approach for this?

| Date_1_field | Date_2_field | Date_3_field |
| --- | --- | --- |

Answer (score 0):

Index-Match will be your best friend here.
First use match to find column number of the columns of interest. And if you have a "primary-key" column (or create your own one), you can subset your data with Index-Match

Edit: [example](https://exceljet.net/articles/index-and-match) with more documentation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in row 1, and you only want the cells that end with "_field":

```
=FILTER(1:1,RIGHT(1:1,6)="_field")
```

This will include only the cells where the last 6 characters are "_field".

You will have to change the number 6 to whatever is the length of the string that you want to match, and change "_field" to whatever string you want to match.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My ans:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(1:1,MATCH("Date_"&COLUMN(A1)&"_Field",1:1,0)),"")
```

Put the formula in A4 cell and drag towards right.

[image: Ans]